# 「可能な額を払う」= Pay what you can?

Tags: grammar

In [ALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%8F%AF%E8%83%BD%E3%81%AA%E9%A1%8D&ref=sa), I found the following example sentence:

> 支払可能な額を払う
>
> pay what you can

It's the first time I see the word 額【ひたい】 used in this way and I wonder if this is just a case of mistranslation or if there is such an idiom (and what its usage would be).

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rikaikun/jipdnfibhldikgcjhfnomkfpcebammhp?hl=en

Comment: そ～ですね～[額縁]{がくぶち}の[額]{がく}ですね～。うそです。金額の額ですね～。普通、オンライン辞書って、フリガナとか音声（←クリックしたら声が聞こえるやつ。）とか、ついてないんですかね。今まで気づきませんでしたけど。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not read ひたい but がく from `金額`, `半額` etc. which means an amount of money.